# How to change the default index.html to index.php when you have two index files

Tags: .htaccess

I want to have two index files. one - index.php and one - index.html.
But I want also to make the default file on the server - index.php
(I have two file just on local environment).
I've already tried to add in the .htaccess the row : DirectoryIndex index.php
but the index.html still loaded first.
Is there any solution without deleting one of the files.

Comment: This sounds like cause for confusion somewhere down the line? Why do you want two "index" pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple values:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

In order for this to work you need to allow overrides for indexes in the apache config

```
AllowOverride indexes
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

A common error is that your .htaccess file isn't being read at all.  A good way to make sure your .htaccess is being read is to put a typo in it and make sure you get an error.

Comment: after long time i back to this question. thank you for your answer this is valuable information and very helpful. i just want to add for the coming next to make sure that in local environment to add to hosts file the host 127.0.0.1 www.example.com and than restart apache